# instanceof on enum variables

Tags: java, enums, instanceof

**EDIT:  Please skip reading details of this question, it's a simple oversight.**

ORIGINAL MESSAGE:

So apparently instanceof on enum variables is a weird thing, an example:

Let this be enum definition:

```
public enum CardType {
  CLERIC,
  UNDEAD,
  TACTICIAN;
}
```

Let this be usage of instanceof on variable of this enum:

```
public SimpleDeckBuilder(Object... definition) {
  for (Object def : definition) {
    if (def instanceof CardType) {
      allowedCardTypes.add((CardType) def);
    }
    if (def instanceof CardDef) {
      allowedCards.add((CardDef) def);
    } else {
      Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getName()).severe("Unsupported def class " +   def.getClass().getCanonicalName());
      throw new RuntimeException("Unsupported definition for SimpleDeckBuilder " +   StringUtils.toString(def));
    }
  }
  ...
```

And this actually doesn't work

```
Deck clericDeck1 = new SimpleDeckBuilder(CardType.CLERIC).build(5);
```

brings exception:

```
SEVERE: Unsuported def class heroes.CardType

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unsupported definition for SimpleDeckBuilder heroes.CardType               Object {  CLERIC: CLERIC  UNDEAD: UNDEAD  TACTICIAN: TACTICIAN  }
```

How to check if a given variable is actually of a given enum type?

Comment: one else is missing after first if in SimpleDeckBuilder, this question is human error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple oversight:

```
if (def instanceof CardDef) {
```

should be

```
else if (def instanceof CardDef) {
```

Answer (score 0):

One "else" is missing after first `if` in `SimpleDeckBuilder`, this question is human error

Answer (score 0):

an "else" is missing before `if (def instanceof CardDef) {`

As a result, in the scenario where the enum is CardType, it goes inside the first "if" clause and does the job, but then it goes also inside the second that checks for "cardDef", and because it is a "CardType" it goes in the else clause that prints the error.